# Ayuda con programa C obtener Mac Addres

Tags: c, linux

Hola me gustaria saber si me pudieran ayudar con el siguiente error que me arroja el programa, consta de tres codigos los cuales son:

Lic2.h -> que es el header

```
#ifndef _LIC2_H_
#define _LIC2_H_

#define LIC_OK                       0
#define LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED  -1
#define LIC_INVALID_ADAPTER         -2

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int licGetMacAddress(char * adapter, unsigned char mAddress[6]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* LIC2_H_ */
```

Lic2.c-> que contiene las funciones a usar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include "Lic2.h"

int licGetMacAddress(char * adapter, unsigned char mAddress[6]) {
int x, i;
int fd;
struct ifreq ifr;
char direcMac[20];

/* Initialices output variable */
memset(mAddress, 0, mAddress);

/* Validates adapter name */
if (!adapter)
  return LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED;
if (!strlen(adapter))
  return LIC_NO_ADAPT_NAME_PROVIDED;

 /* Gets adapter's macaddress */
 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
 strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , adapter , IFNAMSIZ-1);
 ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
 close(fd);
 memcpy(mAddress, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);

 /* Verifies if adapter doesn't exist */
 x = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  if (!mAddress[i]) x++;
  if (x == 6)
  return LIC_INVALID_ADAPTER;

  return LIC_OK; 
   }
```

ejemplo.c --> que contiene el metodo main para ejecutar las funciones

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Lic2.h"

int main () {
int status, i;
unsigned char mAddress[6];

status=licGetMacAddress("eth0", mAddress);
if (status!=LIC_OK) {
  printf("Error al obtener el Mac Address: %d \n", status);
} else {
  printf("Mac Address: ");
  for (i=0; i<6; i++)
    printf("%02X", mAddress[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
return status;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo claro esta en linux mediante

```
 gcc lic2.c ejemplo.c -o getId
```

me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Lic2.c: In function ‘licGetMacAddress’:
Lic2.c:17:24: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘memset’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
memset(mAddress, 0, mAddress);
                    ^
In file included from Lic2.c:3:0:
/usr/include/string.h:66:14: note: expected ‘size_t’ but argument is of type   ‘unsigned char *’
extern void *memset (void *__s, int __c, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
```

Comment: El error ya te dice exáctamente lo que está fallando, estás pasandole mal los parámetros a [`memset`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). Repasa la documentación de la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La firma de `memset` es la siguiente:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Y tu estás haciendo la siguiente llamada:

```
memset(mAddress, 0, mAddress);
```

Es decir, el tercer parámetro, que se supone que debería indicar el número de elementos a incializar, realmente está recibiendo un puntero...

La llamada correcta debería ser:

```
memset(mAddress, 0, 6);
```

Aprovechando la ocasión, fíjate que ese número (el `6`) debe ser exactamente el mismo que el número que figura en la creación de la variable:

```
unsigned char mAddress[6];
```

Este tipo de valores no deberían incluirse directamente en el código porque suponen un problema:

- En algunas partes del código no será obvio el adivinar por qué se usa un literal en vez de otro diferente
- Si el literal cambia en una parte del código tendrás que modificar manualmente dicho literal en todo el código, lo que puede suponer una tarea compleja.

Para evitar esta problemática acostúmbrate a usar `#define` para asignar un alias al literal:

```
#define MAX_ELEMS 6

int main()
{
  unsigned char mAddress[MAX_ELEMS];

  // opción 1 (válida para cualquier tipo de arreglos)
  memset(mAddress, 0, MAX_ELEMS * sizeof(unsigned char));

  // opción 2 (válida unicamente para arreglos en la pila)
  memset(mAddress, 0, sizeof(mAddress));
```

Si resulta que tienes que modificar el literal, con hacer un único cambio conseguiras que todo el código se readapte al recompilar.

Answer (score 1):

`memset` espera el tamaño del buffer como tercer parametro.

debes usar:

```
memset(mAddress, 0, sizeof(mAddress));
```

Esto dejara todos los bytes del arreglo en 0.

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta caí en que no había indicado el tamaño de cada elemento del arreglo (`unsigned int`) al llamar a `memset`. No olvidemos que `memset` trabaja en bytes. En tu código deberías tenerlo en cuenta también.